# string not printing properly

Tags: c++, string

I've used the following code for getting a string and using its first character to make another string:

```
char gramG[100],aug[100],start;
cout<<"\nEnter the grammar:\n";
cin.getline(gramG,100,'.');
start=gramG[0];
aug[0]=start;
aug[1]='\'';
aug[2]='-';
aug[3]='>';
aug[4]=start;
aug[5]=char(13);
cout<<aug;
cout<<aug[0];
```

In the above code when i'm printing 'aug' it prints as ' ¶'->A ' if A is my start symbol. If i am printing only aug[0] then it is printing correctly A. But when i am printing the string as a whole the aug[0] value is printed as some garbage. Please help.

Comment: Why not use `std::string` and its `operator+=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aug is treated as a 0-terminated character array. 0-terminate it.

```
aug[6] = 0;
```

Comment: In fact, what's the point of `char[5]`? That's a carriage return character.

Comment: @suszterpatt i want that enter character at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

you have to terminate the string with null value  
for c++ the null value is \0
 use this 
`aug[6] = '\0';`
this should work;